# Opaque text over transparent box

Tags: html, css, text, transparency

I would like to have opaque text within my transparent box. Here is a code-sample:

HTML:

```
<div id="Transparent_Box">                                          
    <div class="text">                                          
    <h1>Some opaque text</h1>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Transparent_box {      
    url(../images/header-bg.png);
    background:url(../images/header-bg.png) repeat-x\0/; 
    background-position:center bottom, left top;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#FFF;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);  

}

.text {
float:left;
margin-top:30px;
width:490px;
margin-left:20px;
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.text h1 {
    font-weight:900;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height:34px;
    margin-top:8px;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Because of inheritance, the text always appears transluscent. Is there no way to get a nice opaque text over my transparent box?

---

Thanks that was exactly it... I have now also added a background which is a transparent .png
It looks like this:

```
background-image:url(../images/header-shadow.png), url(../images/header-bg.png);
background:url(../images/header-bg.png) repeat-x\0/; 
background-position:center bottom, left top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
```

This should work under IE8 and below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a transparent background color instead of opacity. No extra markup required.

```
div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CswEU/)

Comment: Note that rgba does not work in IE8 or below.  If you need support for IE8, you could fallback to a filter or a background image with transparency.

Comment: A little graceful degradation is okay in my book.